# Filter Steps of a task showing its subtasks - Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where there are two steps to perform a task, Step 1 and Step 2

Step 1 further has 3 actions while step 2 has further 2 actions, as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv6vl.png)

I want to filter the steps. When I filter step 1, it should show all actions of step 1. But when I apply the filter, it shows only 1st action of step 1, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bmhB.png)

How can I apply a filter so that it shows all actions associated with a particular step?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column, in C2, put :

```
=if(b2="","",if(A2="",C1,A2))
```

add drag downwards.

Idea : use column C as filter, but generate the content using the data in column A.

Hope it solves.